# Kill Android Activity if webview is loading

Tags: android

Would like to ask if there's a way to kill / move to another activity in Android if the webview is loading for too long, say example 5 seconds.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "onLoadFinished" callback or something similar you could use to determine whether the webview hast finished loading. (You would need such a check to determine when it's "too long").
I just looked through the available listeners on WebView and found none, that could be of use for this.
So, I think, no, there is no easy way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(isStillLoading())
                         //move to the next activity
                }
            },3000);
```

you have to impliment the method isStillLoading

Comment: Hi, how do I use the isStillLoading() method?
it says in Android studio that it cannot resolve the method

Comment: you can't just use the' isStillLoading' method...you'll have to implement it. if you post your code it would be a lot easier to tell

Answer (score 0):

You can listen the progress of page loading using `WebClient` -

```
private boolean loadingFinished;

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
        loadingFinished = false;
        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       loadingFinished = true;
    }
});
```

User `Handler` to check if the `webview` is loaded or not after 5 seconds -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Will get executed after 5 seconds
                    if(!loadingFinished)
                         //move to the next activity
                }
            },5000); //5000 miliseconds.. i.e. 5 seconds
```